# How to query from two tables with the condition of a third

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables:
location
user_location
image

I need to make a query that takes all the locationes liked by the user toggether with locations images that are in the third table image.

For now i managed to do this:

```
"SELECT Location.* FROM Location LEFT JOIN UserLocation ON Location.id = UserLocation.location_id WHERE UserLocation.user_id=:user_id:
```

But It only retrives the locations that the user liked. now i need the images of every location. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT l.*, (ul.user_id is not null) as hasUser
FROM Location l LEFT JOIN
     UserLocation ul
     ON l.id = ul.location_id and
        ul.user_id = :user_id:
```

The `where` clause filters the output in such a way that it turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't think you understood. I need also the images of each location that are in image table

Comment: This is what I cannot do. I can take locations that the user likes but I cannot take images from the third table in the same query